# How to create a mesh out of an imported model in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to create a game using three.js, but I'm running into some issues regarding the imported 3D models. I've created them in Blender and used the `gltf-blender-IO` plugin to make it easier to work with. However, I can't exactly move the model without it being a mesh. How do I create a mesh out of the model in order to fix this issue?

The full code is [here.](https://repl.it/@SwedishFish/Importing-Models)

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
 var width = window.innerWidth;
 var height = window.innerHeight;
 renderer.setSize(width, height);

 camera.aspect = width / height;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

// controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

camera.position.z = 3;

// ambient light
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xF0F0F0, 4.5);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// directional light
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 5.0);
directionalLight.position.set(5, 0, 5);
directionalLight.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
 
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
directionalLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;
 
directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 0;
directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 15;
 
directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = 5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = 5;
directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -5;

scene.add(directionalLight);

// Load a glTF resource
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader;
loader.load(
 'Fox.glb',

 function ( gltf ) {

  scene.add( gltf.scene );

  gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
  gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
  gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
  gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
  gltf.asset; // Object


 },
 // called while loading is progressing
 function ( xhr ) {

  console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

 },
 // called when loading has errors
 function ( error ) {

  console.log( 'An error happened' );

 }
);

  
// end main

function update() {

};

function render() {
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

function loop() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

 update();
 render();
}

loop();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Are you referring to the type of `gltf.scene` when you say "the model is not a mesh"? A scene object is a 3D object similar to meshes, lines or point clouds. So it is possible to transform it and thus move it in 3D space.

Comment: My issue is that i dont know how to set up the model as a variable in order to manipulate the position, rotation, etc.

Comment: Try to define a variable called `model` in global scope (where you define you scene and camera) and then assign `gltf.scene` to it in the `onLoad()` callback. You can then do stuff like `model.position.x = 1` at all places in your code.